# Content com code points (entity) ou caracteres unicode

Tags: html, css

No site [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_entities.asp) tem a referência de todos os caracteres - especiais, símbolos, alfanuméricos. Não entendi a finalidade de se ter essa representação dos caracteres. No exemplo abaixo o output é o mesmo, só muda a entidade.

1. Quando devemos usar `CSS entity` e/ou quando usar o caractere?
2. Há diferença entre escrever de uma forma ou outra?

---

```
\00A9 => ©
©     => ©

\0041 => A
A     => A
```

---

```css
.copy1:before{content:'\00A9'; margin-right:3px}
.copy2:before{content:'©'; margin-right:3px}
.copy3:before{content:'\0041'; margin-right:3px}
.copy4:before{content:'A'; margin-right:3px}
```

```html
<div class="copy1"></div>
<div class="copy2"></div>
<div class="copy3"></div>
<div class="copy4"></div>
```

Comment: Não posso afirmar, mas uma vantagem possivel é que se usar entities seria para aproveitar o CSS em diferentes documentos/páginas HTML com diferentes codificações, por exemplo, usar um CSS `\00C3` que seria  `Ã`, ele funcionaria bem tanto em uma página UTF-8 quanto uma página windows-1252... Agora se fizer diretamente algo como `div:after { content: 'Ã'; }` com certeza terá problemas dependendo da codificação que salvou o documento `.css`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O w3schools parece que inventou esse nome "css entities", inspirado nas [html entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). Isso aí é uma lista de *code points* unicode, que podem ser usados "escapados" com `\`. Mas também pode usar o caractere diretamente como você mostrou. A [especificação atual](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax-3/#string-token-diagram) diz que vale isto:

[image: string token diagram - as inline svg on the spec]

Então não tem problema utilizar caracteres unicode diretamente como valor do `content`, **contanto que** seu arquivo esteja salvo e seja servido com a codificação correta – no caso UTF-8, mas caracteres em outras codificações também funcionam se tudo estiver sendo salvo e servido corretamente.

Comment: +1 Eu realmente imaginei que tinha algo errado neste nome, pessoalmente sempre achei o w3schools uma péssima referencia de pesquisas (que estiver lendo isto posteriormente não confunda w3schools != w3.org)

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento pior que nem estava procurando sobre isso, foi por acaso que cheguei nele. Como eu uso os caracteres comuns no `content`, acabei abrindo a questão. Vou acrescentar o nome correto ao titulo.